# Android WebDriver not able to enter alphanumeric character

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate a mobile website on android device, using Android WebDriver library.

When the script enters some alphanumeric characters , eg Test12345, in a text field the textbox shows "TEST!@#$%" as entered text. It is true for any alphanumeric word starting with capital letter.

But, if I make the first character a SMALL character or a number then correct word is inserted.

Here is the code which I am using (same scenario happens on any textbox field)

```
driver.get("http://www.google.com");
WebElement searchBox = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
searchBox.sendKeys("Test12345");
```

Is it a bug or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this is a bug. As a workaround you can type any (except NULL U+E000 or "\xEE\x80\x80" in UTF-8) character before your string. E.g. you can start typing with sending two SHIFT (U+E008 or "\xEE\x80\x88" in UTF-8) characters, or one CLEAR (U+E005 or "\xEE\x80\x85" in UTF-8) character. Just anything unprintable, and after that type your string.

Answer (score 0):

FYI: I've confirmed the bug still exists. I'm looking at the android webdriver code to see if I can fathom out why it's occurring. I have some ideas, it's likely to be in one or other of:

```
java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/android/library/AndroidKeys.java 
java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/android/library/EventSender.java
java/client/src/org/openqa/selenium/Keys.java
```

and related to mapping keys between Selenium-Webdriver and Android.

I have found another workaround, similar to the one mentioned by Ivan. Mine involves splitting the text into 2 parts, the first capitalized character e.g. the `T` and use sendKeys to send it; then send the rest of the text e.g. `est12345`

```
searchBox.sendKeys("T");
searchBox.sendKeys("est12345");
```

Ugly, shouldn't be necessary, but a practical option that doesn't involve sending extra (unprintable) characters.